# Bad Event Tracking Code - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

have you had this problem with GA?

The Landing Pages report has a (not set) entry.

A pageview hit must precede event hits in order for the event hits to include the page that they fire from. When event hits aren't preceded by a pageview, Google Analytics doesn't have the page for the event hits, so their page is (not set).

Verify that tracking code for property SITE sends a pageview hit before sending any events.

Google Tag Assistant Recordings can help you verify that your hits are sent in the correct order.

Any suggestions would be great please. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's very likely that it needs a code change to fix this